# Bias Random Generator Mini-program

Tags: java, random, input, while-loop, counter

I'm working on a small programming assignment for my Algorithms class in JAVA.

I'm trying to figure out how to implement my while loop correctly, but I'm having no luck.

I have this program set up to where the method I created puts an edge on 1, to where a 1 is returned more likely than a 0 would be. I'm trying to get the while loop to run 10,000 times and have two counters, countZeros and countOnes to see how many of each showed up out of the 10,000 times.

```
public class BiasedRandom {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int countZeros = 0, countOnes = 0;
    double value = randomNumberGen(1); 

    // while loop here
    // while(value < 10000)
  }

  public static double randomNumberGen(double n) {
    double r = Math.random();
    double p = 0.6;
    if (r > p)
      return 0;
    else
      return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Leading questions: What do you want to do in the loop? How many times do you want to do it, and how are you going to keep track of when you've done it enough times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int countZeros = 0, countOnes = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        int value = randomNumberGen();
        if (value==0)
            countZeros++;
        else if (value==1)
            countOnes++;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad number");
    }

    System.out.println("0: "+countZeros);
    System.out.println("1: "+countOnes);
}

public static int randomNumberGen() {
    double r = Math.random();
    double p = 0.6;
    if (r > p)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

I used the classical `for` loop format for the loop, and changed the return type and parameters of `randomNumberGen()` to match what is done in the method.